# Losing seconds when I modify a datetime

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have an Excel Macro which modifies the EXIF "Date taken" field for a JPG photo.  Basically I add or subtract a decimal value from the datetime value which I have retrieved from the EXIF data and then put the new datetime value back.

For example, if TimeDelta is 12.0, then it should advance the datetime value by 1/2 day (12 hours).  If the TimeDelta is 36.0 then it should advance the datetime value by 1 day and 12 hours.

It is working ALMOST correctly - I lose the seconds, that is the date, hour and minute are correct, but with 00 seconds.

Here are excerpts from my code:

```
Dim sDateTemp As String, NewDateTaken As Date, TimeDelta As Single, Time24 As Single
Time24 = 24#
NewDateTaken = CDate(sDateTemp) + (TimeDelta / Time24)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: What is an example of the string pulled from EXIF?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are implementing your conversion procedure but you should not be losing the seconds.

```
Sub t()
    Dim sDateTemp As String, NewDateTaken As Date, TimeDelta As Single, Time24 As Single
    Time24 = 24#
    TimeDelta = Int(12)   'no sense in pretending that we can get a decimal into a single
    sDateTemp = "26-AUG-2015 09:36:45"
    Debug.Print sDateTemp
    Debug.Print CDate(sDateTemp)
    NewDateTaken = CDate(sDateTemp) + (TimeDelta / Time24)
    Debug.Print NewDateTaken
End Sub
```

Results from the VBE's Immediate window:

```
t
26-AUG-2015 09:36:45
08/26/2015 9:36:45 AM 
08/26/2015 9:36:45 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JEEPED I have resolved the issue. The string returned from the EXIF metadata does NOT include the seconds field.

The seconds field must be there somewhere as the photos sort in the right order before I change the datetime field but not afterwards.

Oh well, I can live with this....RDK